# How to find a comments' count ... or even articles' count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, relying on guide's blog tutorial:http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Trying to learn how to write a method myself.

The guide did both article and comments ie, belongs_to & has_many relationship.

So, thought why not try to find out the totality of comments.

This is the method I wrote for Comments controller:

```
    def total_number_of_comments 
        @article = Article.all
        @comments_total = @article.comments.count
    end
```

Then I put this in article's view index.html.erb

```
 <p>Total number of comments:</p>

 <%=  @comments_total %>
```

On the index page, it doesn't show anything.

So, what am I doing wrong?

And, I don't want just a "correct" answer. I'd like to understand what I'm missing here.

But what I'm befuddled here is how to think this out.

I hesitate to do this because it would prolong the post, but I thought why not try to do count of articles too.

So, here's what I did:

In Article model

```
      def self.total_number_of_articles
          Article.all.count
       end
```

In Article controller

```
  def total_number_of_articles
      @articles_total = Article.total_number_of_articles
  end
```

Then in index.html.erb of Article View again, I put this:

```
<p>Total number of articles:</p>

<%= @total_number_of_articles %>
```

Again, nothing shows up in terms of count in either comment or article.

So .... clearly I'm missing something here.

**EDIT**

The comment (total_number_of_comments)  method was sorta based on this: (from railsguide)

```
    def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Comment: A Rails controller renders the view that correspond to the action you are calling (unless you use `render` or something). So if you are displaying `index.html.erb`, `total_number_of_comments` in the controller will not be called, unless you do it in a before filter, manually call it from the `index` method or just move the code in question to `index`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl, sorry, wrote one comment in response, then deleted it. What do you mean move the code to index? Oh, you mean put the method in the index.html.erb? Isn't that against the whole point of MVC? How do I do it in before filter or manually call it from the index method?

Comment: See the answer by @user2005659 who is trying to explain the same to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you missed, I would happy to explain you.

1. Here

   ```
   def total_number_of_comments 
    @article = Article.all
    @comments_total = @article.comments.count
   end
   ```

   You have to do this

   ```
   def total_number_of_comments 
       @comments_total = Comment.all.count // simple solution  
   end
   ```
2. Next is , you didn't used proper instance variable.

   ```
    def total_number_of_articles
       @articles_total = Article.total_number_of_articles
    end
   ```

   See yourself

   Total number of articles:

   ```
   <%= @total_number_of_articles %> // this is wrong
   ```

   You assigned `@articles_total` but used `@total_number_of_articles`. if you use `@articles_total` it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function index in your controller.
calling a `GET` on `/articles/index` calls the controller function index, you should set `@articles_total = Article.total_number_of_articles` in your index function in controller. You have it in a function in your controller that is not getting called.